# Xcode: UIButton set background color WHERE tag is equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I would like to set a new background color of a button where 'tag' is equal to a random number which is generated in the Timer action.

In my VIEWDidLoad:

```
UIButton *firstButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2);
    firstButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x95A5A6);
    [firstButton viewWithTag:1];
    [self.view addSubview:firstButton];

UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(fullwidth/2, 0, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2);
secondButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x95A5A6);
[secondButton viewWithTag:2];
[self.view addSubview:secondButton];

UIButton *thirdButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
thirdButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2);
thirdButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x95A5A6);
[thirdButton viewWithTag:3];
[self.view addSubview:thirdButton];

UIButton *fourthButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
fourthButton.frame = CGRectMake(fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2, fullwidth/2);
fourthButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x95A5A6);
[fourthButton viewWithTag:4];
[self.view addSubview:fourthButton];

timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(timerOUT:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
NSLog(@"TIMER: %@", timer);
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

My Timer Action:

```
 -(void)timerOUT:(NSTimer*)sender
{
    int lowerBound = 1;
    int upperBound = 5;
    int rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);

    UIButton *lightUpButton = (UIButton*)[firstLevelView viewWithTag:rndValue];
    lightUpButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x1ABC9C);
}
```

Comment: The timer works but the background-color of the UIButton doesn't change @DheerajKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tag of button like this:-

```
[btn settag:1];
```

and in your timer check the `rndValue` then use switch case or if else to change the color of button.
like:-

```
if(rndValue==1)
{
// change the color of first button
}
```